# A globe without borders

Tags: globe

I would very much like to purchase a globe that has no political borders. I don't want the continents all diced up into countries and I certainly don't want any names or labels: just the geography of our planet. I suppose I wouldn't mind geographical wonders, tectonic plates, or other such intrinsic features labeled, but I want nothing political.

I've searched and searched and haven't been able to find anything. Does anyone know where I could purchase such a globe?

Comment: The Globe is just physical terrain  http://www.1ststoptravelstore.com/Columbus_World_Globes/Columbus_Desktop_Globes/Hamburg_illuminated_16inch_desktop_world_globe.htm [$299]